# OCUnit & NSBundle

Tags: unit-testing, resources, ocunit, nsbundle

I created OCUnit test in concordance with "iPhone Development Guide". Here is the class I want to test:

```
// myClass.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface myClass : NSObject {
    UIImage *image;
}
@property (readonly) UIImage *image;
- (id)initWithIndex:(NSUInteger)aIndex;
@end


// myClass.m
#import "myClass.m"

@implementation myClass

@synthesize image;

- (id)init {
    return [self initWithIndex:0];
}

- (id)initWithIndex:(NSUInteger)aIndex {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"image_%i", aIndex];
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"png"];
        image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        if (nil == image) {
            @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"imageNotFound"
                reason:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image (%@) with path \"%@\" for current index (%i) wasn't found.",
                    [name autorelease], path, aIndex]
                userInfo:nil];
        }
        [name release];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [image release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

And my unit-test (LogicTests target):

```
// myLogic.m
#import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "myClass.h"

@interface myLogic : SenTestCase {
}
- (void)testTemp;
@end

@implementation myLogic

- (void)testTemp {
    STAssertNoThrow([[myClass alloc] initWithIndex:0], "myClass initialization error");
}

@end
```

All necessary frameworks, "myClass.m" and images added to target. But on build I have an error:

`[[myClass alloc] initWithIndex:0] raised Image (image_0) with path \"(null)\" for current index (0) wasn't found.. myClass initialization error`

This code (initialization) works fine in application itself (main target) and later displays correct image. I've also checked my project folder (`build/Debug-iphonesimulator/LogicTests.octest/`) - there are `LogicTests`, `Info.plist` and necessary image files (`image_0.png` is one of them).

What's wrong?

Comment: Building off of kpower's solution, I came up with the following [Xcode: TEST vs DEBUG preprocessor macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748087/xcode-test-vs-debug-preprocessor-macros/6763597#6763597).

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Found only one solution for this problem.

When I build my unit-tests, the main bundle's path is not equal to my project's bundle (created .app file). Moreover, it's not equal to LogicTests bundle (created `LogicTests.octest` file).

Main bundle for unit-tests is something like `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.3.sdk/Developer/usr/bin`. And that's why program can't find necessary resources.

And the final solution is to get direct bundles:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[myClass class]] pathForResource:name ofType:@"png"];
```

instead of

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"png"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using [self class] is also possible, leaving that line like this: `NSString *path = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:name ofType:@"png"];`

Comment: As far as I know, when you develop standard iPhone application, the only bundle is used to store all your sources & resources. So, theoretically, any "custom" (created by yourself) class can be used here. But I didn't check this idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've been looking for this answer for the past 3 days

Comment: After struggling with this for quite a while, this answer was a god send. Though almost 6 years old, it is still a great solution for those like me wanting to unit test static libraries that include bundles.