# NSBundle while unit testing with OCUnit returns (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsbundle, ocunit

**Problem :** Retrieving from NSBundle returns `(null)` while running Unit Test, returns valid object on run time.

**What have I done ?**

I have searched SO with similar problems, apple's developer and other online resources for this problem but with no luck.

I have tried solution from SO questions; [OCUnit & NSBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067015/ocunit-nsbundle), [NSBundle pathForResource returns nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157480/nsbundle-pathforresource-returns-nil).

All solutions I went through online point out to one thing **Bundle for run time and tests are different.**

All of them recommend having

```
[NSBundle bundleForClass: [self class]];
```

instead of

```
[NSBundle mainBundle];
```

**Question :** I don't understand if the above fix is with setter injection or in the source file itself. ? Is there any other way I can test the method `getIpAdress` ?

**Code**

Class that returns (null),

```
// iRNetworkingObject.m

@implementation iRNetworkingObject

-(NSString*) getIpAdress {
     NSDictionary *infoDict = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] infoDictionary];
     NSString *lookUpAdress = [infoDict objectForKey:@"LookUpIpAdress"];
     return lookUpAdress;
}
@end
```

Test class

```
- (void) testGetIpAdress {

    iRNetworkingObject* networkingObject = [[iRNetworkingObject alloc] init];
    NSString* testCase = @"192.168.2.1";
    NSString* encondedString = [networkingObject getIpAdress]];

    STAssertTrue([testCase isEqualToString:encondedString], @"Not equal");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bundleForClass:` is important in test code, to make sure you get the application bundle instead of the test bundle. You shouldn't have to do that in production code.

Your key `@"LookUpIpAdress"` is misspelled. Is that the problem?

Comment: Ok, so the production code can have `mainBundle` and I will have to use something like `setter injection` from the test code to pass the bundle ? Naa, spelling's fine, it is working for run time and I simplified my code in the question ;)

Comment: There's no need for setter injection. The test should be able to verify the actual value.

Comment: that is the problem, it is not. :(

Comment: I copied your code. Works fine. Any failure is more descriptive if I use `STAssertEqualObjects([networkingObject getIpAdress], @"192.168.2.1", nil)`.

Comment: yeah that tells me `(null) should be equal to 102.168.2.1`. is there anything else I might be missing ?

Comment: Not in the code you've shown. I'd start adding some logging, and compare the logs between production & test.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26473/discussion-between-kishor-kundan-and-jon-reid)